# Creating the rounded corner container with some color on border?

Tags: css

Is it possible to create such a rounded corner gray layout in css3 which is around the content and right side bar [Livesite](http://www.fairview.org/about/S_013970)  and image is here

[image]
Sorry i m beginner at css3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple

```
.round {border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;

}
```

Just add this class to whatever you want rounded. You can also change the radius.

For the border `border:10px solid #E0DDD7`

You can replace the `#E0DDD7` with Black, Silver, Blue etc...

If you are looking to just have top rounded corners, You can

```
.round-top {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 24px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius: 24px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius: 24px;  
}
```

Comment: You can set the border like this `border:10px solid #E0DDD7;`

Answer (score 4):

```
.element {
    /* set border styling */
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;

    /* set border roundness */
    border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Because `border-radius` is a CSS3 feature and quite new, the `-moz` and `-webkit` versions are recommended to support older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you can create this with yourself check this:

### http://css3generator.com/